# How can I train a TensorFlow (or Keras, or Caffe) model to detect an object and also its distance from the camera?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, caffe, object-detection

I have a dataset with 1000s of labeled images, only one class (cars) and also their respective distances from the camera at the moment the pictures were taken.

I’d like to train a TensorFlow (Keras or Caffe examples would also be okay) model to detect other cars (this I already know how), but also to try and predict their distances from the camera as accurately as possible given what was learned from the dataset.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In principle it does not change much form the problem of detecting the class of an object. You have to have a dataset with object types and distances to be able to train.

But, **don't expect wonderful accuracy** distance is something that is not directly encoded in an image. There is no way to truly know the difference between a big ball far away or a small ball up close. **Knowing the class of the object can help**, since specific objects have typical sizes. So a chair has a pretty standard size, so the relative size in the image can be better interpreted as distance.

Another thing that can help is having **multiple cameras in a configuration something like our eyes**. In this configuration you probably don't even need to train a model. The image displacement between cameras should be enough to say the distance of everything on the screen. There are probably opensource software that implement this.

As for the implementation of the first idea. You should build a tensorflow graph for extracting features. and create some extra layers for classifying  and some extra layers for predicting the distance. (search for multi-headed networks for more details)

Your question is pretty vage, so I can't really give a more specific answer as to what architecture to use or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To estimate the distance the following approaches can be used:

1. Using stereo camera. In this case, distance is computed using the image displacement
2. Using depth-from-mono model. This is typically a deep neural network trained on corresponding labelled data.
3. If you calibrated the camera assuming a 'flat world', the distance can be estimated from the height position of the bounding box. In this case, the lowest point of the bbox is projected on a imaginary ground plane.